# If a cell is > 10 copy and paste colum to sheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm working on an Excel 2007 Spreadsheet for work and I need to take a value on 'Sheet 1' and IF its larger then 10, I need to take an entire column and past it to 'Sheet 2'.

How would I do this? Where would I start?

UPDATE:

```
Sub TopComp()


For Each i In Worksheets("All Competition").Range("E32:BL32")
 If i.Value > 9 Then
 ady = i.EntireColumn.Cells(1).Address
 i.EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("Top 10 Competition").Range(ady)
 End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The problem I am having now is when it paste the colum, which is awesome. It is leaving spaces for the empty ones. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Hey @user2788749, can you tell us a bit more about the problem? Is the value in every row on a sheet and needs to be evaluated repeatedly, or is it one value per workbook? Or per worksheet? Do you need to evaluate this over many workbooks or just one?

Comment: Yeah sorry. At the end of each column there is a value. If that value is higher then 10 I'd like to copy the entire column and past it into another sheet. It would repeat that for all columns about 60 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT #1, pictures from last post removed**

OK, let's try this instead. You start out with a workbook like this:

[image: start]

Try running this modification of your code:

```
Sub TopComp()

Dim i As Range, TargetRng As Range
Dim TargetCounter As Long
Dim AllSheet As Worksheet, TopSheet As Worksheet

'declare worksheets for easy reference
Set AllSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Competition")
Set TopSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Top 10 Competition")

For Each i In AllSheet.Range("E32:BL32")
    If i.Value > 9 Then
        TargetCounter = TargetCounter + 1
        Set TargetRng = TopSheet.Cells(1, TargetCounter).EntireColumn
        i.EntireColumn.Copy TargetRng
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

That should give you to the following, which is what I think you want:

[image: end]

--

Cool -- let's say you start with the workbook looking like this:

You can run this code to populate with the columns that have an end value > 10:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CheckColumns()

Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, _
    ColIdx As Long, TargetColCounter As Long
Dim SheetOne As Worksheet, SheetTwo As Worksheet
Dim ColRng As Range, TargetRng As Range

'assign sheets for easy reference
Set SheetOne = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set SheetTwo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'identify the last row and last column to set bounds on loop
LastRow = SheetOne.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol = SheetOne.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

'loop through the columns
For ColIdx = 1 To LastCol

    If SheetOne.Cells(LastRow, ColIdx).Value > 10 Then
        TargetColCounter = TargetColCounter + 1
        Set ColRng = Range(SheetOne.Cells(1, ColIdx), SheetOne.Cells(LastRow, ColIdx))
        Set TargetRng = Range(SheetTwo.Cells(1, TargetColCounter), SheetTwo.Cells(LastRow, TargetColCounter))
        ColRng.Copy TargetRng
    End If

Next ColIdx

End Sub
```

Comment: I apologize but I am confused by this. It doesn't seem to actually add the column to the sheet like the other answer. Do I need to also ad din to have it add that column?

Comment: hey @user2788749, I'm not sure I understand your note. This script iterates through the last row of each column and compares the value to 10: if the value is > 10, that column is copied to "Sheet2", if the value is =< 10 then that column is skipped. Am I misunderstanding your goal?

Comment: ...just got back to work this morn. Tried this, works great. I have ONE last problem. When it puts that it starts from column one. So it deletes the title labels I have. Is there a way to make it start at column E and then paste?

Comment: So for example...I need it to START the past at column 'E'. Thanks so much!

Comment: EDIT: I fixed it. Probably not the most efficient way, but I got it to do exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much you were a huge help.

Answer (score 2):

Select the test cell on the first sheet and run:

```
Sub kolumnizer()
    If ActiveCell.Value > 10 Then
        ady = ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Cells(1).Address
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range(ady)
    End If
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

I am using *Sheet2* rather than *Sheet 2*

**EDIT#1:**

This version will loop over all the columns in the first sheet and copy the column to **Sheet2** if some cell in the column has a value greater than 10:

```
Sub kolumnizer()
    Dim i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim nLastColumn As Long, nFirstColumn As Long
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    nFirstColumn = r.Column
    For i = nFirstColumn To nLastColumn
        Set r = Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
        If wf.Max(r) > 10 Then
            r.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Start on the first sheet**

**EDIT#2**

Version 3 allows **you** to pick the range:

```
Sub kolumnizer3()
    Dim i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim nLastColumn As Long, nFirstColumn As Long
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick your range", Type:=8)
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    nFirstColumn = r.Column
    For i = nFirstColumn To nLastColumn
        Set r = Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
        If wf.Max(r) > 10 Then
            r.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: this is AWESOME...I'm so close. This is doing exactly what I want it to, but its only doing it when i select one individual cell. How would I adjust it to run this to a whole range of 60 colum cells?

Comment: So..for examle I have 60 different colums each with a differnt number value, I'd like for excel to look at each value, if its OVER 10 then copy and paste into "Sheet2".

Comment: **Do all the cells have to be greater than ten or can just one cell be greater than 10??**

Comment: So, if that one cell is larger then the whole column would be copied and pasted and then move onto the next column. If that one cell in the next is larger then 10 that whole column us copied and pasted, repeat.

Comment: so...when you say some cell I see that r = ActiveSheet.Used Range hwo do I set r to be the range that I want. Other wise this is perfect!

Comment: **O.K.**  ActiveSheet.UsedRange is all the columns that have values............how would you like to pick the range??

Comment: I would like to select the rang, because I also have some labels and color coding titles in there.

Comment: See my EDIT#2 (Version#3)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. The two of you combined got me through this problem. Thanks!